# Prevent any navigation or buttons from working on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension I am writing that allows me to click on divs and highlight the entire div. Some of these divs I am going to click on to highlight are navigation links or buttons. How do I completely disable anything from happening on the page in javascript?

I tried window.onunload but I am currently having no luck.

Code so far:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
window.onunload=function() {
return false;
}
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery you can do something like:

```
$(document).bind('click', function(ev) {
    ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Let me know if that works. We can refine it later if not.

Comment: Good point. Then you should iterate over the elements and nullify the inline events and store them using jQuery.data() when you need to restore them back at some point.

Comment: Then he can always use $(document).unbind('click').